# Controlling Plotly icons

Tags: json, graphics, plotly

Can I control [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) top icons in it JSON structure?

For example, if I want to remove the button export to png, as indicated bellow, is it possible?

[image]

I looked at [Plotly Javascript Reference](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently [pull request #23](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/23) open to address the lack of this feature.

In the meantime, you can get rid of the icon using CSS:

```
.modebar .modebar-group:first-child a:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```